# IF statement formula for Google Sheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Statement:
IF value of 1st Google sheet cell A2 is equal to value of cell A2 of 2nd Google sheet, then copy A3 value of 2nd Google sheet into  A3 of 1st Google sheet.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking about, show your sample data...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(A2='2st Google sheet'!A2; '2nd Google sheet'!A3; )
```

or:

```
=HLOOKUP(A2; '2nd Google sheet'!A2:A3; 2; 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods you can try:

=IF(A2=firsSheet!A2,SecondSheet!A3)

=HLOOKUP(A2,SecondSheet!$A$2:$A$3,2,0)

=FILTER(SecondSheet!A3,A2=FirstSheet!A2)

or you can use "Index-Match" formula